# Email Name using Google App Script - Make a user name appear in the "From" section of the receivers email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I compose a Gmail, my name appears to the receiver (e.g. Quoc Dat).

But when I use this code to send mails, not my name but only my email address appears to the receiver.

How can I fix this code so that my name appears to the receiver?

```
function onFormSubmit(){
   var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var dataRange=sheet.getDataRange();
   var data=dataRange.getValues();
   for(var i=1;i<=data.length-1;++i){
      var row=data[i];
      if(row[3]!='a'){
         var address=row[2];
         var message="Hello";
         MailApp.sendEmail(address,"Hello",message);
         sheet.getRange(i+1,4).setValue("a");
         SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `name` Advanced Parameter and the `options`

Currently:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(address,"Hello",message);
```

Must Be:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(address,"Hello",message,{name:'Your Name Here'});
```

Or:

```
var address = "example@gmail.com";
var message = "The body of email here";

var objectOfOptions = {//Object literal of advanced options
  name:"Your Name Here"
}

MailApp.sendEmail(address,"Hello",message,objectOfOptions);
```

Link to documentation:
[Apps Script Documentation - MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options)

If your spreadsheet has the user name, you'll need to get that.  If you don't have the user name associated with the email address, "MailApp" won't automatically get the user name.